# TypeError: dispatcher.useInsertionEffect is not a function

Tags: typescript, typeerror, backstage

when I am running a .tsx file, I am getting this error

TypeError

Message
dispatcher.useInsertionEffect is not a function

Stack Trace
TypeError: dispatcher.useInsertionEffect is not a function
at useInsertionEffect (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1639:21)
at Insertion (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@emotion/styled/base/dist/emotion-styled-base.browser.esm.js:54:133)
at renderWithHooks (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14986:18)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17812:13)
at beginWork (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19050:16)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3946:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3995:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4057:31)
at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23960:7)
at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom-v17/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22775:12)

It was running fine but started giving trouble suddenly. Couldn't actually sort the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`useInsertionEffect` is a React 18 feature, and you probably are depending on a version older than that in your repository. We officially only support `^16.13.1` and `^17` though - you may want to check your dependencies so that you don't inadvertently pull in React 18 features.

Comment: Hi @Eldloppa. Thank you for the response.  Yes, one of my dependency was outdated. Was able to sort that out. Thanks a lot..